# Pluggable objects in MVVM (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to design architecture of my application in such way, that I'll be able to add new elements to it easily and in maximum separation from the core application (possibly even from external assemblies).

Let's say, that I have a window with a combo-box, which allows choosing from those elements. Every element has its own editor and main application knows nothing about it - just provides a place, where the editor may be embedded. The following picture should explain the concept:

[image: Concept of application]

Now this works I already checked, that I can do the following in XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ExposedControl}" />
```

However, this is rather big violation of MVVM concept, because MainWindowViewModel contains (indirectly) a View (Element's control).

If elements were hardcoded, this could be solved by `DataTemplate`s for elements' ViewModels. But this would require tying application and elements and that's something I'd like to avoid.

How can I design architecture to allow elements providing parts of the UI, but also keeping the MVVM pattern intact?

Comment: I think your own implementation of a `DataTemplateSelector` should do the trick: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i think you are describing prism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396